# AngularJS - Can't use filter to set variable in view

Tags: angularjs

I'm using a filter to calculate values, but then I want to access them later on.

Here's a snippet of my code:

```
app.controller('CreateProposalCtrl', function() {
     $scope.EstimatedCostItem = [];
});
```

-

```
app.filter('EstimatedValue', function() {
        return function(input, arguments) {
             ...blah blah calculations
             return calculations;
        };
    });
```

I'm not sure how the HTML should be presented.

This displays exactly what I want..BUT I need it to set a variable so I can access it somewhere else..

```
<span ng-repeat="foo in bar">
    {{ Type.JobTypeID | EstimatedValue: form }}
</span>
```

I've tried:

```
<span ng-model="EstimatedCostItem[Type.JobTypeID]" ng-bind="Type.JobTypeID | EstimatedValue: form"></span>
```

And:

```
<span ng-bind="EstimatedCostItem[Type.JobTypeID]">{{ Type.JobTypeID | EstimatedValue: form }}</span>
```

And:

```
<span ng-init="EstimatedCostItem[Type.JobTypeID] = (Type.JobTypeID | EstimatedValue: form)"></span>
```

Nothing seems to set a variable.  I'm stumped :(

Comment: When do you need to set a variable ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filter syntax only works within specific Angular expressions. Expressions that use plain JavaScript cannot use the `foo | bar` filter syntax, as it's not valid JavaScript.

What you *could* do is use [$filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter):

```
var value = $filter('EstimatedValue')(foo);
```

Remember to inject `$filter` into your controller.

With that said, this probably isn't the best use of a filter. Why not create a scope function that calculates and stores the value? Something like:

```
$scope.EstimatedValue = function(foo) {
    var value = doSomeCalculations();

    // store for usage elsewhere
    this.estimatedValuesCache[foo] = val;

    return val;
};
```

Comment: Great.  Thanks for this.  To answer your question, I want to reuse my filter in other controllers so don't want to copy over a function.